# Impossible to stop caching?

Tags: html, asp.net, caching

I'm having immense problems with caching, I can't seem to turn it off. I've searched the internet high and low but to no avail.

I've tried turning chromes caching off, tried using firefox (with cache turned off) and finally had to use queries (i.e. script src="main.js?123") to get the browser to update. Now I'm working on a ASP-script and even the querying isn't working. I am however typing the ?123 etc in the browser instead of in the html/php-file I normally work on.

I tried changing the http headers when working in html but that didn't work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

I've also tried changing the ASP cache settings but no luck:

```
Response.addHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ' HTTP 1.1.
Response.addHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" ' HTTP 1.0.
Response.addHeader "Expires", "0" ' Proxies.
```

What's going on? Is there some machine caching along the way, like a proxy cache? Is that determined by my ISP or by my web hotel? Why didn't changing the http headers work then?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be at the web server or browser level.  Both are capable of caching.  Check your web server settings and when in doubt, Shift+F5 (clears cache and refreshes).

Comment: I've tried shift+f5, and turning cache off completely in the browser (i.e. ctrl+shift+i -> settings -> "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"). I'm thinking it's not local.
My "web server settings", that's kind of vague. I have a few servers running apache and one running windows with .net4.0. Same problem.